# Does a nonzero Jacobian over a domain means that the map is one to one?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

I have a question when learning the Jacobian, if given a map:$f:\mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$ has a nonzero Jacobian, could it be proved that  $f$ is one to one?

My thought:$$\mathbf{d(f(x))}=\frac{\partial \ \mathbf{f}}{\partial \ \mathbf{x}} \mathbf{dx}  $$
so when $\mathbf{d(f(x))}=0$, with nonzero determinant, we can conclude the $d(f(x))$ is only the approximation of the $\Delta{f(x)}$, so can you help me to improve the proof or give a counterexample? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the right words: "determinant" instead of "determinate" ; moreover it's more classical to say Jacobian instead of "Jacobi determinant"

Comment: I got it, thank you!@JeanMarie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: $f(x, y) = (e^{x} \cos y, e^{x} \sin y)$. This has nonzero Jacobian (check it!) but not one-to-one: $f(0, 0) = f(0, 2 \pi)$. (This function actually the same as the function $\exp: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.)

However, once the Jacobian is **nonzero and constant**, your statement would be true, but it is a [famous conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture) which is still open.